# Saving a file from one server to another

Tags: php, centos, centos7

I have a web form that I will be hosting on a centOS web server. The code that I have written, will take the data that has been entered, and save it to an excel spreadsheet to a specific location. i also have a file server, this is where I would like to have the file saved to. this is the first time that i have done a server to server file save/copy/transfer. on the web server, would i have to install an ftp client to accomplish this? When testing the program locally on my computer, this is how i currently have the destination path set up.

```
file_put_contents('C:\Users\username\Box Sync\Driver Check In\Shortage'.
     $month. '\Shortage'.date('m-d-y').".csv", $result, FILE_APPEND);
```

with the code being hosted on the web server, how can i change the destination path to point to my file server?

Comment: [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) would be your best bet

Comment: You could get PHP to push out files to a ftp server, if ftp is an option.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: i will take a look at both of these options. would i still need to use `file_put_contents` though?

Comment: you need to create the csv file and save it locally first before you can upload it, so the answer is yes

Comment: http://www.medianotions.de/code-snippets/php/file_put_contents-via-ftp-mit-ftp_file_put_contents/ here is a put together solution for your reference

Comment: terrific. i will look into this and see if i can get it working. thank you for your help

Comment: @bobdon glad to be of help, please consider accepting my answer or voting it up if you find it helpful. By the way, you need to use the @ tag to address the person you wish to reply to, when you follow up on comments. You as the OP gets notified whenever someone comments on your post, we as respondents don't get notified unless you @ us.  Feel free to @ me if you get stuck putting to solution together.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script of how to upload file from your localhost to any FTP server.

Source: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#101408)

```
   <?php 
    $host = '*****'; 
    $usr = '*****'; 
    $pwd = '**********';         
    $local_file = './orderXML/order200.xml'; 
    $ftp_path = 'order200.xml'; 
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");      
    ftp_pasv($resource, true); 
    ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login"); 
    // perform file upload 
    ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/public_html/abc/'); 
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII); 
    if($upload) { $ftpsucc=1; } else { $ftpsucc=0; } 
    // check upload status: 
    print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete'; 
    print "\n"; 
    // close the FTP stream 
    ftp_close($conn_id); 
    ?>
```